# Output object tree as string

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a little side project and I stumbled at on specific point. The crazy part it is that it seems very simple, yet I'm bashing my head for more than hour now.

I have an example object such as:

```
{
  l1_1: {
    l2_1: {
      l3_1: 'l1_1_l2_1_l3_1',
      l3_2: 'l1_1_l2_1_l3_2'
    },
    l2_2: {
      l3_1: 'l1_1_l2_2_l3_1',
      l3_2: 'l1_1_l2_2_l3_2'
    },
    l2_3: {
      l3_1: 'l1_1_l2_3_l3_1',
      l3_2: 'l1_1_l2_3_l3_2'
    }
  },
  l1_2: {
    l2_1: 'l1_2.l2_1',
    l2_2: 'l1_2.l2_2'
  }
}
```

I need to output each path to the deepest children of the object, like so (as a separate string):

```
l1_1.l2_1.l3_1
l1_1.l2_1.l3_2
l1_1.l2_2.l3_1
l1_1.l2_2.l3_2
l1_1.l2_3.l3_1
l1_1.l2_3.l3_2
l1_2.l2_1
l1_2.l2_2
```

The problem is that the object may not have the same deepnest for each children. like the provided example. ( it may have 2, 3, 4 or even 5 levels )

The idea is that I will use those strings to check if the object are used in specific liquid files, where they use the following syntax `{{ 'l1_1.l2_1.l3_1' | t }}`

Here is what I have come up at this point.

```js
const obj = {
  l1_1: {
    l2_1: {
      l3_1: 'l1_1_l2_1_l3_1',
      l3_2: 'l1_1_l2_1_l3_2'
    },
    l2_2: {
      l3_1: 'l1_1_l2_2_l3_1',
      l3_2: 'l1_1_l2_2_l3_2'
    },
    l2_3: {
      l3_1: 'l1_1_l2_2_l3_1',
      l3_2: 'l1_1_l2_2_l3_2'
    }
  },
  l1_2: {
    l2_1: 'l1_2.l2_1',
    l2_2: 'l1_2.l2_2'
  }
}

function iter(obj, keyTarget){
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    const val = obj[key];
    if(typeof val == 'object'){
      keyTarget = keyTarget ? `${keyTarget}.${key}` : key;
      iter(val, keyTarget)
    } else {
      keyTarget = `${keyTarget}.${key}`;
      console.log(keyTarget)
    }
  });
}

iter(obj, false)
```

I know why the code is not working, since the loop passes multiply times at the same object, the values are passed and shared between them and I get the wrong values, but I just can't figure a workaround that I can clear the string and at the same time keep it for the next object.

Any insights will be much appreciated.

Comment: In other words you need to output each _leaf_ i.e. nested prop without childrens?

Comment: @hindmost yep, pretty much the whole tree structure of the object. I don't need the final value of the children, just the path to it.

Comment: Tree structure is not the same as you described above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could collect the path and if a leaf is found add this path to the result set.

```js
function getPathes(object, path = []) {
    return Object
        .entries(object)
        .reduce((r, [k, v]) => r.concat(!v || typeof v !== 'object'
            ? path.concat(k).join('.')
            : getPathes(v, path.concat(k))),
            []
        );
}

var data = { l1_1: { l2_1: { l3_1: 'l1_1_l2_1_l3_1', l3_2: 'l1_1_l2_1_l3_2' }, l2_2: { l3_1: 'l1_1_l2_2_l3_1', l3_2: 'l1_1_l2_2_l3_2' }, l2_3: { l3_1: 'l1_1_l2_3_l3_1', l3_2: 'l1_1_l2_3_l3_2' } }, l1_2: { l2_1: 'l1_2.l2_1', l2_2: 'l1_2.l2_2' } },
    pathes = getPathes(data);
    
console.log(pathes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach without storing the path.

```js
function getPathes(object, path = []) {
    return Object
        .entries(object)
        .reduce(
            (r, [k, v]) => r.concat(v && typeof v === 'object'
                ? getPathes(v).map(v => k + '.' + v)
                : v
            ),
            []
        );
}

var data = { l1_1: { l2_1: { l3_1: 'l1_1_l2_1_l3_1', l3_2: 'l1_1_l2_1_l3_2' }, l2_2: { l3_1: 'l1_1_l2_2_l3_1', l3_2: 'l1_1_l2_2_l3_2' }, l2_3: { l3_1: 'l1_1_l2_3_l3_1', l3_2: 'l1_1_l2_3_l3_2' } }, l1_2: { l2_1: 'l1_2.l2_1', l2_2: 'l1_2.l2_2' } },
    pathes = getPathes(data);
    
console.log(pathes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 2):

You could create recursive function using `reduce` method to return array of all the paths.

```js
const data = {"l1_1":{"l2_1":{"l3_1":"l1_1_l2_1_l3_1","l3_2":"l1_1_l2_1_l3_2"},"l2_2":{"l3_1":"l1_1_l2_2_l3_1","l3_2":"l1_1_l2_2_l3_2"},"l2_3":{"l3_1":"l1_1_l2_3_l3_1","l3_2":"l1_1_l2_3_l3_2"}},"l1_2":{"l2_1":"l1_2.l2_1","l2_2":"l1_2.l2_2"}}

function getPaths(data, prev = "") {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    let path = prev + (prev.length ? '.' : '') + k
    if (typeof v == 'object') r = r.concat(getPaths(v, path))
    else r.push(path)
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const paths = getPaths(data)
console.log(paths)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. got to give it to @Nina Scholz since she was 1 sec faster. +1 nonetheless. Thanks.